# iOS app distribution with Testflight via customers account

Tags: ios, testflight, ad-hoc-distribution

My company has developed an iOS application for an external client. They have done some initial testing with us distributing the app via our testflight account. They now want to test it on a wider audience. They have decided to use their own TestFlight account and handle all the logistics of giving iPads to users and managing the distribution/testing of our app.

Is it possible for me to give them my .ipa file that they can in turn sign with an Ad Hoc apple certificate they create/mange then use their testflight account to distribute.

In short my company does not want to give away our source code nor burden the client with installing/learning xcode just to compile the app with their certs over ours. They are not developers but feel comfortable using an apple developer account and testflight. They would prefer not to set up and use xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: Can they add you to their Apple developer account?

Comment: assuming they don't ming giving their certs over, can they not let you access the test flight account temporarily?

Comment: @Jamie Forrest I could ask them. They are pretty reasonable. Kind of new to all of this can you explain how this might work if they were willing to? I've been making an archive in xCode, signing with my Ad Hoc and uploading to TestFlight. if I am on their developer account won't they still have to use xCode with distribution cert to make .ipa?

Comment: @Nitin Alabur Would I put their Ad Hoc Distribution cert on my Mac/xCode then archive and sign with their cert then upload that build to their TestFlight site???

Comment: You'll need their AdHoc Distribution Cert (including the private key), the AdHoc Distribution provisioning profile signed using that cert, to build an app using their credentials. If you cannot get a provisioning profile/cert/key with their developer account, then you cannot build an app using their credentials

Comment: @RichP If they add you as a team member on their (company) account you'll be able to build an ipa for them. They will have to submit it to the app store though. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281246/is-it-possible-to-let-somebody-else-upload-and-distribute-my-app-in-apples-app